# Want to show child trade number for each parent trade number in SKU group using sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have table with with SKU & Tradenumber  columns. I want to create a new column saying childTM it have to show child of each parent in a SKU group using SQL Server. Below is my Inputs and outputs.

| SKU | TradeNumber |
| --- | --- |
| AB1 | 3070 |
| AB1 | 2070 |
| AB1 | 1070 |
| CD1 | 5036 |
| CD1 | 3621 |

Output

| SKU | TradeNumber | ChildNumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB1 | 3070 | 2070 |
| AB1 | 2070 | 1070 |
| AB1 | 1070 |  |
| CD1 | 5036 | 3621 |
| CD1 | 3621 |  |

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`LAG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) window function should help you achieve this (assuming the order as displayed in your tables)

```
declare @tradenum table (SKU char(3), TradeNumber int)

insert into @tradenum
values ('AB1',  3070),
('AB1', 2070),
('AB1', 1070),
('CD1', 5036),
('CD1', 3621)

select *, lag(TradeNumber) over (partition by SKU order by TradeNumber )
from @tradenum
order by SKU, TradeNumber desc
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to ALTER the table:

```
ALTER TABLE <TableName>
    ADD ChildNumber <DataType> NULL;
```

You want to replace  with the actual table name and  with the same data type as TradeNumber (INT, VARCHAR, ...), you may also want to add a Foreign key to the column if you want to enforce that the ChildNumber be one of the values in TradeNumber:

```
ALTER TABLE <TableName>
    ADD ChildNumber <DataType> NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (ChildNumber) REFERENCES <TableName>(TradeNumber);
```